# \r doesn't clear more than one line

Tags: ruby, terminal

Let's say my terminal is 4-columns wide, and I print 4 `X`s and a return character:

```
$ print "XXXX\r"
$ yesyeshellothiscanbeanythig
```

The `\r` returns to the start of the line, so that the characters to follow (`yesyeshellothiscanbeanythig`) can overwrite them.

I want to achieve this effect beyond a single line: when I have five `X` and the final `X` wraps onto a second line, I want `\r` to move back both lines.

What I want:

```
$ print "XXXX\r"
$ overwrite
```

What I get:

```
$ print "XXXXX\r"
XXXX
$ overwrite
```

The first 4 `X`s are printed, and then the fifth `X` is wrapped onto a newline, and then the `\r` only goes to the start of the second line, leaving the 4 `X` intact on the first line.

Is there a platform-independent way to let `\r` go back to the start of the first line? I thought an `\r` would go to the start of the first line if the lines are produced via a wrap rather than an explicit `\n`.

Comment: Your issue seems to be a simple thing to understand (not necessarily meaning that it is easy to solve), but you are writing it as if it is very difficult.

Comment: How/why your lines are being wrapped, again?

Comment: Under "What I want", why do you have `$ print "XXXX\r"`?

Answer (score 2):

`\r`, by definition, only moves the cursor to the start of the current line. There is *no* standardized way to move the cursor to other lines - different platforms have different ways to do it. On Windows, you'd use the Win32 console API to move the cursor, and on Linux/UNIX/OS X you would use ANSI escape codes to move the cursor around.

The Ruby Curses library can do some of this, but I'm not certain it works on Windows, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is documented somewhere but current versions of MRI support some ANSI escape codes on Windows when writing to the console.

Comment: Actually, the "by definition" found in ECMA-48 (the relevant standard) is more complicated than that.  It has the cursor (active presentation position) going to the *home* position on the same line.  The home position is configurable (though the given SLH sequence is rarely used). Some terminals have settable margins -- and carriage return is affected by those.